# Google analytics tracker for Vaadin

Tags: google-analytics, vaadin

I'm using this plugin: https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/googleanalyticstracker

in code example says to use

```
GoogleAnalyticsTracker tracker = new GoogleAnalyticsTracker("UA-658457-8", "vaadin.com");
mainWindow.addComponent(tracker);
```

but GoogleAnalyticsTracker doesn't implement interface Component, so when I try add it to view, I'm getting

```
ava.lang.ClassCastException: org.vaadin.googleanalytics.tracking.GoogleAnalyticsTracker cannot be cast to com.vaadin.ui.Component
```

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same error with the `GoogleAnalyticsTracker` not extending `Component`. The following code worked for me:

```
private void initGATracker(final String trackerId) {
   tracker = new GoogleAnalyticsTracker(trackerId, "demo.vaadin.com");

   // GoogleAnalyticsTracker is an extension add-on for UI so it is
   // initialized by calling .extend(UI)
   tracker.extend(UI.getCurrent());

   // Track all page views
   tracker.trackPageview("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
GoogleAnalyticsTracker tracker = new GoogleAnalyticsTracker("UA-658457-8", "vaadin.com");
tracker.extend(myUI);
tracker.trackPageview("/samplecode/googleanalytics");
```

and see java doc for more details because the newest version extends AbstractJavaScriptExtension.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm using exactly such code and it doesn't work.
I also tried using navigator.addViewChangeListener(tracker), but did not help.

Comment: Please post your code with description and I will try to help you.